# How can I optimize this regex to get better performance?

Tags: .net, regex, negative-lookbehind

I'm trying to optimize one of my .NET app's regular expression.

Regex: `(?<!WordA\s(?:WordB\s)?)(WordB\s)?WordC`

Logic:

- Find matching WordC
- Join WordB to match (if present right before WordC)
- Don't match anything if WordC (even if preceeded by WordB) is preceeded by WordA

Should Match:

- WordC
- WordB WordC

Should Not Match:

- WordA WordC
- WordA WordB WordC

The expression works but as you can see the WordB is present two times in the expression so I'm trying to remove one of them to get better performance.

Note: "Words" are in fact complex expressions.

Is there any way?

Comment: What's wrong with performance, how did you measure it?

Comment: It looks like you are not trying to get better performance, you just want to shorten the regex.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I normally use Regex101 step count but since it's flavor does not support a quantifier inside a lookbehind, I can't measure this way. Each "WordX" in the expression can be a long/complex expression (ie: 500+ chars) and I match it against a lot of strings (that can be long too) so I figured that the longer the total expression is, the more step it's gonna take to process; so if could shorten it by removing duplicate parts it would be better. This is only a feeling ("don't duplicate your code" they say lol), but I might be wrong... :-) I measure it using a stopwatch.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew well it's short enough, it just feels like poor design... Length does not matter but step count does.

Comment: Step count is not a direct proof on the regex efficiency. Using a stopwatch, yes, might be a better bet. Still, do you have access to the code? Or do you want to be able to cram everything into the regex pattern?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the code is simply "new Regex(expression).Match(content)". but the expression is dynamically built and it's run against a bunch of "content" that may be long. In short: the code is already optimized but it seems that the expression could be improved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224250/discussion-between-don-madrino-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with "optimizing" the `(?<!WordA\s(?:WordB\s)?)(WordB\s)?WordC` regex (that is a combination of `(?<!WordA\s)WordC` and `(?<!WordA\s)WordB\sWordC`) is that `WordB` and `WordC` are separated with whitespace, and a negative lookbehind does not make the regex engine skip the matched phrase once there is `WordB WordC` preceded with `WordA`, it only skips the position where it failed, so `WordC` will match if you just use `(?<!WordA\s)(WordB\s)?WordC`. The lookbehind must restrict both `WordB\sWordC` and `WordC` that is why you must repeat the optional `WordB` in the lookbehind pattern, the same way you would use it in the two "destructured" patterns shown above.

So, with a plain string regex, there is no other way.

A workaround involving some code change can look like

```cs
var rx = @"(WordA\s)?(?:WordB\s)?WordC";
var strings = new List<String> {"WordC", "WordB WordC", "WordA WordC", "WordA WordB WordC"};
foreach (var s in strings)
{
    var m = Regex.Match(s, rx);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", s, (m.Groups[1].Success ? "NO MATCH" : m.Value));
}
// => WordC: WordC
// => WordB WordC: WordB WordC
// => WordA WordC: NO MATCH
// => WordA WordB WordC: NO MATCH
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/51hWOK).

In the `(WordA\s)?(?:WordB\s)?WordC` regex, `(WordA\s)?` captures `WordA` with a whitespace is captured into Group 1, and if it matches, we know we need to discard the match. If the Group 1 `.Success` value is *false*, it means the match is valid.